# R sort summarise ddply by group sum

Tags: r, pivot-table, plyr

I have a data.frame like this

```
x <- data.frame(Category=factor(c("One", "One", "Four", "Two","Two",
"Three", "Two", "Four","Three")),
City=factor(c("D","A","B","B","A","D","A","C","C")),
Frequency=c(10,1,5,2,14,8,20,3,5))

  Category City Frequency
1      One    D        10
2      One    A         1
3     Four    B         5
4      Two    B         2
5      Two    A        14
6    Three    D         8
7      Two    A        20
8     Four    C         3
9    Three    C         5
```

I want to make a pivot table with sum(Frequency) and used the ddply function like this:

```
ddply(x,.(Category,City),summarize,Total=sum(Frequency))
  Category City Total
1     Four    B     5
2     Four    C     3
3      One    A     1
4      One    D    10
5    Three    C     5
6    Three    D     8
7      Two    A    34
8      Two    B     2
```

But I need this results sorted by the total in each Category group. Something like this:

```
Category City Frequency
1      Two    A        34
2      Two    B         2
3    Three    D        14
4    Three    C         5
5      One    D        10
6      One    A         1
7     Four    B         5
8     Four    C         3
```

I have looked and tried sort, order, arrange, but nothing seems to do what I need. How can I do this in R?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a base R version, where `DF` is the result of your `ddply` call:

```
with(DF, DF[order(-ave(Total, Category, FUN=sum), Category, -Total), ])
```

produces:

```
  Category City Total
7      Two    A    34
8      Two    B     2
6    Three    D     8
5    Three    C     5
4      One    D    10
3      One    A     1
1     Four    B     5
2     Four    C     3
```

The logic is basically the same as David's, calculate the sum of `Total` for each `Category`, use that number for all rows in each `Category` (we do this with `ave(..., FUN=sum)`), and then sort by that plus some tie breakers to make sure stuff comes out as expected.

Answer (score 5):

This is a nice question and I can't think of a straight way of doing this rather than creating a *total size* index and then sorting by it. Here's a possible `data.table` approach which uses `setorder` function which will order your data *by reference*

```
library(data.table)
Res <- setDT(x)[, .(Total = sum(Frequency)), by = .(Category, City)]
setorder(Res[, size := sum(Total), by = Category], -size, -Total, Category)[]
#    Category City Total size
# 1:      Two    A    34   36
# 2:      Two    B     2   36
# 3:    Three    D     8   13
# 4:    Three    C     5   13
# 5:      One    D    10   11
# 6:      One    A     1   11
# 7:     Four    B     5    8
# 8:     Four    C     3    8
```

Or if you deep in the Hdleyverse, we can reach a similar result using the newer `dplyr` package (as suggested by @akrun)

```
library(dplyr)
x %>% 
  group_by(Category, City) %>% 
  summarise(Total = sum(Frequency)) %>% 
  mutate(size= sum(Total)) %>% 
  ungroup %>%
  arrange(-size, -Total, Category)
```